# Tire Gem Ruby on Rails Faceted Search Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, faceted-search, tire

I am trying to replicate a working curl request I have using the Tire Gem.  However when using the library it does not seem to let me within a facet set multiple fields.  I want to set both the terms and the filter fields however they just write over each other.  Here is the working facet part of the curl request that I am trying to replicate:
"facets":
   {
   "person_value_f":
       {
            "terms":
            { 
              "field":"person_value_f",
              "size":10
            },
            "nested":"dossiers",
            "facet_filter" : 
            {
                "term" : { "person_value_f" : "NO"}
            }
       }
    }

Here is my code to try and replicate this:
    facet "person_value_f", :nested => "dossiers" do
              filter(person_value_f,"NO")
              terms "person_value_f"
            end

Being the terms is the last line of code that is the only included section in the curl command.  Looking at the Tire library it does not seem to let you do this, which seems very very bizarre.  How do I get tire to essentially do faceted navigation if my facet is person_value_f and the value I want to see is "NO" for this? Thanks in advance